# I want to divorce vs I want divorce

Tags: grammar

Is there a difference between

> I want divorce

and

> I want to divorce.

And concerning the second one should I rather say

> I want to divorce my wife

And is "to divorce" A verb here or  or object of the verb "want"?

Comment: _I want **a** divorce_ is the correct syntax for the first example

Answer (score 2):

*[Divorce](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/divorce?showCookiePolicy=true)* can be either a noun or a verb.

In your first sentence, it is used as a noun, but it needs an indefinite article.

> I want **a** divorce.

In the second sentence, *to divorce* is a verb form, an infinitive, but it is used as a noun phrase.

Because *divorce* is almost always transitive, it almost always needs an object. Your alternative suggestion. *I want to divorce my wife* would sound much more natural than *I want to divorce.*  However, the latter would not be wrong, especially if the context made it clear, but would sound stilted.

Answer (score 1):

You would say

> I want **to** divorce my wife.

and

> I want **a** divorce from my wife.

Here, in the first example "divorce" is a verb (thus the infinitive) and the second is a noun (thus the indefinite article).

Answer (score -2):

Nothing wrong with both the sentences, but "I want to Divorce", sounds more correct to use.